# How can I manually convert sheet music into a MIDI, and define what track they are on?

Tags: midi, keyboard

I am learning how to play the piano, and am a bit new to the technology in audio.  I read this [great introduction into MIDI](http://www.midi.org/aboutmidi/intromidi.pdf) but need to know how I can construct a MIDI file from sheet music.

Why am I asking? I want to create a MIDI file that will take advantage of the cooler features of my PSR-e423 keyboard.  One feature is that it will "grade" you on tempo, and correctness of notes.  This grading system only works on notes played on Channel 1, and this channel can be easily substituted for other instruments.  I can enable/disable 5 concurrent channels.

I think I've gone too far randomly downloading software (scala, etc) and have no idea if the software I found accomplishes my goal.  I'll even work with a free trial if you know of one.

Any tips are appreciated.  I can't wait to get started!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Ableton Live](http://www.ableton.com/live-8) or [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/index.php) or some other program to create the MIDI file.

Once you have chosen a program attach your keyboard to your computer via MIDI.  Then, you can either record yourself playing the song live and fix the notes you miss, or you can use your keyboard as an input device to enter the notes manually.

When you are done, simply export into a MIDI file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend notation software, such as Finale.